# Ado Brackets Efficient File Finder

Tags: adobe-brackets

Is there anyway Adobe Brackets Editor find a file as fast as typing a filename and avoid going through the sidebar? Much like finding a text with ctrl-f?

Comment: https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Shortcuts

Comment: You can use `Ctrl + Shift + O`.

Comment: ctrl+shift+O works, just wondering what is the scope of it finding files, that is which directories?

Comment: @TheOne: I've posted an answer below that hopefully addresses your follow-up question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned – use *Navigate > Quick Open*, which you can also access via the shortcut Ctrl-Shift-O.

Quick Open is very powerful: you can type just an abbreviation or parts of a filename to find it with less typing.  For example, typing "fbu" or "fooutil" will find "FooBarUtils.js".

---

*Edit:*
to answer the question about scope... Quick Open searches in your entire project. Brackets treats the root folder you have open (the root of the folder tree you see at left) as your project. To choose a folder, choose *File > Open Folder*.

There's no way to restrict Quick Open to just a subfolder within that project, but you can type part of a *folder name* and Quick Open will factor that into the search results. For example, typing "foo/bar" or even "fbar" will list "foo/bar.js" or "foo/xyz/bar.js" higher in the results. This is useful if you have many files with similar names within your project.